# Longest sentence where all consecutive characters are in the same 3ʳᵈ tone

Tags: mandarin, sentence-structure, tones, sandhi

What is the longest sentence that can be constructed where all the consecutive characters are in the same 3ʳᵈ tone in Mandarin? I'm sure many people have heard of '请你给我买五百把纸雨伞', but are there any more interesting ones?

Comment: Does this question have an exact answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because even though it's fun and all (I did that kind of games in language school too)  it's not a good fit for the Q&A format of Stack Exchange.

Comment: A more appropriate question could be: *"what's the correct tone sandhi of this sentence? (follows third-tone "nightmare")"*

Comment: Please do not change the question entirely - you’ve just made all existing answers completely irrelevant to the new question.

Comment: @dROOOze Yes, sorry for messing up, I later rolled back. With this new format, are all answers still relevant?

Comment: @blackgreen Hi, do you think I should write a new question following the same wording of the recent question [Longest sentence where all characters have the same sound](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/50766/longest-sentence-where-all-characters-have-the-same-sound)?

Comment: @T-Pioneer Hi, in your opinion, would this new format be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No punctuation

李组长想请尹小雨买两把小伞给老鲁雪伟。

Answer (score 1):

老闆你好，請你給我兩碗炒米粉，晚點我想請我女友。

all is 3rd tones

Comment: If you add "李" before the sentence, it will be longer:-)

Comment: @T-Pioneer hahaha.yes.right.

Comment: too bad, you have to remove the punctuation marks to make it longer than the OP's 11 characters sentence

Comment: @TangHo yes. you are right. but as you know. there is no punctuation marks in the ancient chinese

Comment: How about 請李老闆你晚點給我與我女友兩碗炒米粉

Comment: @TangHo perfect